# What would religion be like on a planet with a nine-year day?

Tags: society, culture, religion

In the world I built the day is very long, 9 years long. This means that the daytime lasts 4.5 years. The sunset lasts 0.3 years and is full of electrical storms. What I'm asking is what kind, if any, religion would this world have?

If any more information is needed please let me know.

> -Very few ever enter the night and survive they also have little concept of the moon and the stars.
>   -People live in large blimp villages.
>   -There is no agriculture.
>   -They are constantly moving to avoid the night.
>   -They are similar in form to humans.

Comment: Why is the night so deadly? Aren't there winds from the day side equalizing the temperature, for the most part?

Comment: it is for the most the main thing that makes it deadly is that most of the water is frozen and plants don't grow(mushrooms do but most are poisonous). Also most of the life in the dark side are predators that would make quick work of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the religion would focus on the travel and journey heavily.  For an example check out this snippet from Lost Odysseys dreams http://lostodyssey.wikia.com/wiki/The_Upstreamers  (incidentally, how is it a game with such moving and perfectly atmospheric side stories manages such large values of narm in the main story.  If it was just directed better it could have been an amazing game!)

I imagine a connection between the constant travel and life will be made.  Life is a constant trip through time as we move along.  Perhaps heaven will be someplace where you can stay in one place and not have to move ever again.

Hell will be night time.  The most defining aspect of hell is darkness.  Your god will almost certainly be the Sun, guiding over and protecting you.  Alternatively hell may be twilight, with the horrible lightning storms; because no one survives to know what comes after the twilight.

There will no doubt be a just-so story as to why they constantly have to travel.  I would imagine it to be either a punishment from god, or a test from him; perhaps both.  Imagine that it use to be that everyone stayed in one place, but people grew lazy and greedy and took for granted all that God had given them without thanking him.  So God made them have to constantly travel, partially as punishment for taking for granted all the wonderful life he gave them, but also partially to encourage them to not stagnant.  By making the move he made then grow and learn and adapt, to better themselves.  Thus equal parts punishment and desire to help them towards moving forward and adapting into things worth of his love.  At the end of life if you grew enough, and grew to appreciate the gifts you were given, you get to go to an eden of eternal light without the need to travel an more.

Alternatively night may be their satan, chasing after them.  God provides protection as they travel and flee Satan.  This version of religion would likely have a strong duality to it.  God get's half the planet, Satan the other half; thus their satan is see as equal to god, not subservient as Satan in Christianity is.

There could be pantheons, but if so it would likely be a pantheon of 'good' gods (or light gods, some may be less then good), vs a single deity night god who is equal in strength to all the other pantheon put together.

This group would never be able to plant food or take up agriculture, thus it would depend on hunting and scavenging for subsistence until they reached a high level of technology (long after their religion had developed.  They would likely emphasis God providing food and hunting for them to help them on their journey.

They would also need limited numbers of people in any area, they can only have as many mouths to feed as there there is food to scavenge; since they can't rely on any of the tricks we use to grow more food.  Thus they would have a heavy tribe culture, with many small groups that may run into each other, but stay mostly separate (or they would have this in the early years of culture where religion formed).  Thus their religion would likely have some focus on how to handle running into new tribes while they traveled.  They would need these tribes to find mates and avoid inbreeding.  I imagine this would result in a high focus on the idea of hospitality and very strict rules on how to treat stringers and strange tribes, enforced by religion.  Look at how the greek gods stressed the importance of hospitality to guests, and punished those who didn't offer it.

Comment: This is very good. Quick note; you are right about the agriculture they don't have it but they have a solution to it, a small animal similar in size to a small cat or rabbit exists that is similar to rats( can live everywhere and very quickly reproduces) called a manerat they eat this and it replaces agriculture because it reproduces so quickly. similar to the ocean ecosystem where there are more sharks than fish because they fish reproduce so qquickly

Comment: @majornorwal animals are far less energy efficent then plants for producing energy (they constantly waste extra energy in living and reproducing).  They need to graze to eat, meaning their still forraging as well.  I think small creatures would be inefficent, but larger creatures designed to be both packmule and food source would likely travel with them.  Still, since the creature would spend half it's time walking it would only have so much time to graze, and would *require* food of a type it can eat (what do you do with your horses if traveling through dessert or mountains?)

Comment: in short, yes I think grazing creatures would be used to expand their food supply, by taking advantage of creatures that can eat food they can't; however, I don't think it would substantially increase the total available food, not enough to allow large communities.  Besides, there are limits travel itself, such as amount of dust kicked up, rate at which you can pass an area, damage earlier wagons leave in roads for later wags etc, that also limit maximum nomad community size.